# Why do we have two words to describe post-mortem medical examination?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

[Autopsy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/autopsy) is defined as

> inspection and dissection of a body after death, as for determination of the cause of death; postmortem examination.

[Necropsy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/necropsy) is defined as

> the examination of a body after death; autopsy.

In practice, [it seems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autopsy) that "autopsy" is generally used when referring to the post-mortem examination of a human body, and "necropsy" refers to the examination of non-human bodies. I see no immediate evidence in the root words that would explain why we have this distinction, except perhaps for the "self" that `αὐτός` refers to being used to describe post-mortem examination of humans specifically, leaving "necropsy" to mean examination of dead bodies in general.

That is all conjecture, however, and it seems like a stretch. So: where do these two separate words come from?

Comment: Bones. But my guess is 'complicated traditional word usage'.

Comment: @PeterShor what did autopsy mean before it was narrowed? It would be interesting if it were the (current) secondary meaning of "A critical assessment or examination after the fact", because "post-mortem" has a business meaning that is similar to that. We do a "post-mortem" after a project is completed, for example.

Comment: Autopsy seems to have originally had the medical meaning of *inspection by sight*. The original phrase for *autopsy* (c. 1800) appears to have been the Latin *autopsia cadaverica* or the French *autopsie cadeverique*, which I assume would have meant "inspection of the cadaver by sight". My comment (which I deleted) speculated that *necropsy* started out life as a euphemism for *cadaverous autopsy* so as to avoid mentioning cadavers.

Comment: There are many cases where we have two words that mean the same thing, and usually it's just because the words were coined independently.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: Coined or minted, it's the same thing.

Comment: There's also 'postmortem'. It's the obscurantist treadmill. Once people learn the old one you have to some up with a new one that people don't understand.

Comment: Hadn't heard of necropsy...

Comment: I always saw the distinction as the same reason that humans are not spayed/neutered - we're sterilized or have our tubes tied or have a vasectomy...humans seem to need to differentiate ourselves from (other) animals.

Comment: Weird that *auto* means *self* in this context. You can't look at your own dead body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word *autopsy* is older, and had the original meaning "to see with one's own eyes". The Oxford English Dictionary writes that it was first used in a now-obsolete sense in the 1600s:

> The action or process of seeing with one's own eyes; personal observation, inspection, or experience. Now rare.

Its current use only dates from the 1800s:

> Med. Examination of the organs of a dead body in order to determine the cause of death, nature and extent of disease, result of treatment, etc.; post-mortem examination; an instance of this.
>
> > 1805    Philos. Mag. 21 240   The distinguishing signs of peripneumony and pleurisy are so uncertain that they have been doubted by some celebrated physicians; they have been so often belied by cadaverous autopsia.

*Necropsy* is a much more recent coinage, and dates from the 1800s:

> 1842    R. Dunglison Med. Lexicon (ed. 3) 470/2   Necropsy, autopsia cadaverica.

Note that in the example given, *autopsy cadaverica* and *necropsy* are synonymous. However, because an autopsy could have been the inspection of any body, it was used in the phrase "cadaverous autopsy" or "autopsia cadaverica". It seems that *necropsy* may have developed as a one-word term to describe the autopsy of a deceased person, though by the 1830s *autopsy* was being used on its own in its current sense:

> 1830    Foreign Rev. 5 502   Two days after the autopsy, which was performed immediately on the emperor's decease, the whole body turned yellow.

However, it can be argued that the 1830 example was really referring to an *autopsy* of a body in general, who happened to be deceased (as there is qualification within the sentence which refers to death). Then, the first use of *autopsy* on its own without such qualification would be in the 1880s:

> 1881    Times 22 Sept. 4/1   The physicians' autopsy [of President Garfield] shows the bullet to be nowhere near where it was supposed to be.

From this, I think that *necropsy* developed as a one-word synonym to *cadaverous autopsy*, and then over time *autopsy* came to be synonymous with *necropsy*.

Comment: So if I'm understanding properly, "autopsy" was originally a term to describe personal observation. "Cadaverous autopsy" was an autopsy as we know it. "Necropsy" came to provide an abbreviation for "cadaverous autopsy", leading to the latter's falling out of usage. Do I have this right?

Comment: @AbbyΨ I believe so. There is nothing in the OED as to *why* any of this happened, but that is the conclusion I came to having read the entries for both terms.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'necro' comes from the Greek *nekros* meaning dead/dead tissue, & the -opsy part comes from the Greek word *opsia* meaning an examination, then necropsy should be the examination of a dead body in general. 'Autopsy' would be examination of ourselves/our body. Maybe by extension "an examination of the *human* body"?