# What do I call a specialist who performs necropsy of a sacrificed animal during a clinical study?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, translation

I'm translating a text where a description of a clinical study is given in which animals are subjected to necropsy. One of the sentences goes like this:

> If they consider it necessary, the **autopsist** may take pictures of macroscopic changes reflecting the damage left by the drug.

But is it really **autopsist**? After all, not autopsy was performed but necropsy. I found almost no results for "necropsist". Are there other options?

The Russian word is [патологоанатом](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%EF%E0%F2%EE%EB%EE%E3%EE%E0%ED%E0%F2%EE%EC), which is basically the same as [pathoanatomist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pathoanatomist) - but googling brings up too few results with the word "pathoanatomist", so I wonder if there might be more widely used terms for this.

Comment: Note that _autopsy_ and _necropsy_ do overlap in usage. Necropsy often, but not mandatorily, involves animals.

Comment: Note that "sacrifice" has strong connotations of religious or spiritual practice.

Comment: In the scientific world, '[sacrifice](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sacrifice)' is the accepted term for this practice. The linked definition 3a is the intended meaning.

Comment: @IconDaemon - because science is the religion of our days.

Comment: "not autopsy was performed but necropsy" - are they different? > https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43052/why-do-we-have-two-words-to-describe-post-mortem-medical-examination

Comment: Upon seeing "necro-" and "sacrificed", I thought I'd stumbled upon the [RPG StackExchange](https://rpg.stackexchange.com).

Comment: There's no verb "to autopse", so we don't have "autopsers" or "autopsists", like we don't say "He was autopsed yesterday".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The word you’re looking for is:

**[pathologist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pathologist)**

An expert in pathology; a specialist who examines samples of body tissues for diagnostic or forensic purposes.

Comment: Likewise *forensic pathologist* for criminal investigations. They perform autopsies/necropsies to determine cause of death and gather evidence for investigation and prosecution.

Comment: Further reading: [Veterinary pathology(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veterinary_pathology)

Comment: This is a very general term, as a pathologist does a lot of things beside autopsy/necropsy - including examining samples taken from living tissue. *Examiner* or *researcher* are equally valid.

Comment: @talmu _"... may take pictures of macroscopic changes reflecting the damage left by the drug."_ is an example of something a pathologist does. _Examiner_ or _researcher_ are too broad.

Comment: @JonPurdy and there lies the potential for strangeness - "pathologist" is popularly associated with "coroner" quite strongly...

Comment: @talrnu The alternatives you suggest are *far* more general than “pathologist”!

Comment: I'll point out that officials who perform autopsies are very often referred to as *examiners*, in the US at least - it may be a general term, but so is *pathologist*, and no "acceptable degree of generalization" was ever specified (in fact the question is quite specific).

Answer (score 4):

Your question initially makes it sound like you're looking for a noun describing the person's *job* (and then "veterinary pathologist" might be correct, I think). But if you're just trying to translate that sentence in context, I would think that the absolute least ambiguous way to translate it would be:

> If they consider it necessary, **the person performing the necropsy** may take pictures of macroscopic changes reflecting the damage left by the drug.

It doesn't matter what their job description is *in general*; what matters in this sentence is that they're the person *performing the actual necropsy which is being discussed in this sentence*.

Alternatively, it's possible that in the original context there is no necropsy *necessarily* being performed, and that the sentence's oblique reference to "the necropsist" is meant to imply that

> If they [who?] consider it necessary, **a necropsy may be performed in order to** take pictures of macroscopic changes reflecting the damage left by the drug.

or

> If they [who?] consider it necessary, **the animal may be necropsied in order to** take pictures of macroscopic changes reflecting the damage left by the drug.

In which case, the least ambiguous translation might be

> If it is desirable to photograph the macroscopic changes reflecting the damage left by the drug, **a necropsy may be performed** for the purpose of taking such photographs.

At which point we're left with a tautology — the sentence has been stripped to its essence, which is nothing at all. Naturally, "if" you consider it necessary to take photographs, then you "may" choose to take them! We have succeeded in conveying no information to the reader. :)

Comment: The last version is better if you stop at the end of the bold bit. You could also change *may be* to *must be* or *is* (or *will be*).

Comment: If you want to avoid the passive voice, “the pathologist may perform an autopsy to....”

Comment: "The pathologist, or any other qualified person, may perform an autopsy to..." ;)

Answer (score 0):

"a specialist who performs necropsy on a sacrificed animal during a clinical study" is **"a veterinary pathologist"**.   A **"medical pathologist"** is an M.D. who performs necropsies on human beings.

> - [Veterinary pathologists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veterinary_pathology) are doctors of veterinary medicine who specialize in the diagnosis of diseases through the examination of animal tissue and body fluids. Like medical pathology, veterinary pathology is divided into two branches, anatomical pathology and clinical pathology.
> - [Veterinary anatomical pathology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veterinary_pathology) **is concerned with the diagnosis of disease based on the gross examination, microscopic, and molecular examination of organs, tissues, and whole bodies (necropsy).**